# Downloading torrent with filtered tracker

Tags: vpn, proxy, utorrent, socks-proxy

I am using `uTorrent version 2.2.1 build 25534`
I have downloaded a few torrents from a site which both the site and its trackers are filtered in my country
Now i have tried solving this problem by using a `VPN` that bypassed the filter which solved the errors on the tracker, but even after that the torrents speed remains at zero !
In the end after a lot of experiment i found that running a Proxy such as `FreeGate` solves the problem ! and the torrents work without a problem.
**Now here are the a couple of questions :**
1- Why is it that even when using the `VPN` my torrents don't download even when the tracker is green and connected ?
2- After checking the settings in the utorrent, i can clearly see that there are no indication that the torrent should be using the `FreeGate` (freegate is a socks proxy which and only works if u set the IP and The port inside a program), of course `FreeGate` does change the internet explorer proxy setting
3- In the end i am sure that the torrents are not downloaded using FreeGate ! but it seems something is using this FreeGate proxy which makes the tracker work ! i want to know what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the port forwarding in the router ? couldn't it be because freegate configured it for you ? In the absence of port forwarding on both side (all sender and receiver), the communication will be blocked.